# Pass the id parameter to invoke a php (SQL Update function) onClick using ajax and jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to invoke an updateVoteCount($id) function onClick of a button using php, jquery and ajax. However, the the id doesn't get passed through to the function.
How can i solve this?
Here is the jQuery part:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
      {
         $('addVote').click(function()
            {
             var  id=("#add-vote-form").serialize();
             $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'voteCount.php',//file where your php function will be run.
             data: id,
             });
          });
    });
</script>
```

here is the php part:

```
<?php
        include 'database.php';

        $id;

        if(isset($_POST['id']) ){
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            updateVoteCount($id);
        }
        header('Location: vote.php');
    ?>
```

Comment: What is the HTML for #add-vote-form

Answer (score 0):

It looks like u have a typo here: 
`var  id=("#add-vote-form").serialize();` 
try to use it 
`var  id=$("#add-vote-form").serialize();`

Comment: this is the html form element for '#add-vote-form'. How do you i get the id of that row passed as a parameter?

    <form action="voteCount.php" method="get" id="add-vote-form">
    <table style="border: 5px solid darkgrey"><tr>
    <td>No.</td><td>ID</td><td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    include 'database.php';
    $popular = retrievePopular();
    for($i =0; $i < sizeof($popular); $i++){
    ?>
 <tr>
 <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $popular[$i][0]; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $popular[$i][1];?></td>
 <td><button id="addVote" name="addVote">Vote</button></td>
    </tr>